# ng-click $event = undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a popover with custom html with angularjs and twitter bootstrap. Since this function has not been implemented in angular-ui, I use bootstrap methods inside angular directive.

I compile the template inside of directive and attach compiled element as content of popover.

It works fine, but when ng-click fired, $event inside of callback is undefined. And I need this $event (through `$event.target`) to get the element, which I'm going to hide and hide it.

The code is simple:

```
mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = function(e) {
                console.log('test');
            };
});

mymodal.directive('testD', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        template: "<a href='#' id='pop-over-link'>Show pop-over</a>",
        scope: {test: '&'},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var templateData = 
            "<button class='btn btn-default btn-sm cancel' ng-click='test($event)'>Cancel</button>";

          var compliedData = $compile(templateData)(scope);

          $(element)
            .popover({html: true,
                      content: compliedData
                     })
            .on('click', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              return true;
            });                                
        }
    }
 });
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nq5Lnvd8/

What I've done wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the directive "testD" instantiates its own scope you can't write the test function in the main controller. Instead you can do it like the following ways.

**First way:**

Write the test function in the directive controller like below:

```
  controller:function($scope){

        $scope.test = function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        };

    },
```

**Second Way:**

Write the test function in the directive link:

```
 link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


         scope.test = function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        };
```

Then you are able to get the event as required.

You can follow up the updated fiddle for more details:

http://jsfiddle.net/Satbir/nq5Lnvd8/6/

Comment: I've used your approach, and it works, but now closing callback fires only once. So, I open popover, slose in with "close button", than open it again and after it I can't close it. And ng-click() method does not fired. How I can find out what is a problem?

Comment: Can you provide the jsFiddle for the same so that I can take a look over that?

Comment: Yep: http://jsfiddle.net/vc4sd1fe/ And here the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153768/how-to-find-out-why-ng-click-does-not-fire-second-time

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. When you define test on the scope of the directive instead it registers the event - see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/h32kgs69/

Adding this function:

```
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.test = function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
```

Because you use an expression binding for test, and do not pass the event into that binding, it is lost by the time it reaches the function in the outer scope. Try using '=' binding instead of '&'.