# How to find out why ng-click() does not fire second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have some code, which works on the jsfidle, and does not work locally.
Inside this code I have the directive which compiles template and appends to DOM. Inside this template I bind some ng-click event (close popover). This event fired once, and when open popover on the second time and trying to close it, it does not work. 
Here the code:

```
mymodal.directive('editable', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        template: "<a href='#' id='pop-over-link'>Show pop-over</a>",
        scope: {test: '&'},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.closePopover = function($event){
              var el = $event.target;
                     $($event.target).parents('div.popover').popover('hide');
          };
          var templateData = 
            "<button class='btn btn-default btn-sm cancel' ng-click='closePopover($event)'>Cancel</button>";

          var compliedData = $compile(templateData)(scope);

          $(element)
            .popover({html: true,
                      content: compliedData
                     })
            .on('click', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              return true;
            });                                    
        }
    }
```

Here the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vc4sd1fe/
How I can debug this situation? Where could be the problem? I am confused why this code perfectly works only once. How can I found wehere to fix it?

Comment: If it works in the fiddle, and not locally, there has to be a difference somewhere, you just have to find it.

Comment: Yep, but there is no obvious difference.

Comment: You're sure the directive above isn't nested in some other piece of code

Comment: Your module is called `mymodal`? If not, this is the main problem.

Comment: just a tip, be careful using `.on` event, because that function is from jquery not angularjs and it does not trigger angular diggest cycle, to bind  a click event to element use ` bind('click,function)'`

Comment: There is no problem with `.on` element events. The main problem with `ng-click='closePopover()` event which fires only once. I've binded it and compiled in the directive, so I'm counfusin why it works so strange.

Comment: @levi if you use bind you have to do the same thing. if jQuery exists , `bind()` actually uses `on()` internally.  [jQuery source viewer - bind()](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=bind)

Comment: @charlietfl nope because if you use ` bind()`  angularjs will trigger diggest cycle. using `on` wouldnt.

Comment: @charlietfl unfortunatly I cannot provide another demo except for this fiddle.
I understand that is is realy hard to say what's wrong with my code, so I would be happy to get some advises about vector of investigation. I suspect that somewhere data-binding is broken and I'm asking about knoledge which things could broke data-binding.

Comment: @levi this will show you it doesn't do what you think http://plnkr.co/edit/3Dnq2nHiFSkpxVzY7WRj?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl there is 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ' in the chrome console - is it ok?

Comment: seems to be a bug in plunker itself, have been seeing that a lot lately. clear console/ clcik stop/run and code works fine

Comment: @charlietfl one thing I've found is the sope for first time popover opened and for the second time are different. And in the second-time scope there are no keys and values for the filling the popover. But opened popover is filled with this values!

Comment: suggest you create a demo that replicates problem

Answer (score 0):

I have made a same environment on local. But didn't get any issues. Anyway check this fiddle for more details or I can send you the html file that I created to test the same code. It works just fine. Th popup is closing on every click.

http://jsfiddle.net/Satbir/cswcopgr/

Just deleted some line of code:

```
 scope:false,
```

and directive:

```
<editable></editable>
```

Please check the same and report me. It would be great to help you.